# 'Google maps' Navigation application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter, google-maps

How to open google maps apk via another apk on android or ios in `flutter`  `react-native`  .. or any mobile technology. I would like to make a navigation system in my application so I want to directly use google maps through my application. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open Google Maps app from your app you could do something like this.

- First set up your url String (what you will send to Google maps app so it knows what directions give):

  ```
  String url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=' +
        currentLocation.latitude.toString() +
        ',' +
        currentLocation.longitude.toString() +
        ' &destination=' +
        lat.toString() +
        ',' +
        lon.toString() +
        '&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate';

  _launchURL(url);
  ```

Where currentLocation means the user current location, and lat and lon means the destination.

- Then just launch that url, using an urlLauncher:

  ```
  void _launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
  ```